# How to drain a CNAME record in Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I currently have a setup that looks something like this:

```
   www.example.com -CNAME-> alb.us-east-1.example.com
   www.example.com -CNAME-> alb.us-west-1.example.com
   ...
```

Each of these records uses latency based routing with a heath check. As of now this successfully  send traffic to a "nearby and healthy" instance (good), but what to do when I want to preemptively drain one instance? *(In this case, an "instance" might be an EC2 instance not behind any LB, or an LB of some strip, or a non-AWS IP, or something else entirely. It's something that has an address that traffic must be stopped from attempting to reach.)*

(**Edit:** by "drain" I'm referring to causing Route53 to quit including a given record in its responses so that traffic will not attempt to contact the ALB instance (or whatever) it points at. Note that anything involving the configuration of an ALB won't work as it's the ALB (etc.) it self I want to prevent traffic from connecting to.)

As far as I can tell, Route53 doesn't explicitly provide that ability, which seems like a curious omission.

What best practices are know for supporting this use case?

---

**Edit:** and for the record, I've Googled around a bunch and found nothing even as useful as what I'm already using. Maybe I'm just using the wrong terms or something?

---

The current best solution I've come up with is to create a "health check" that is carefully constructed to always fail and swap it in for the real health check. But that seems really sloppy as it's tricking the system into giving me what I want rather than actually being what I want.

Another solution I've looked at, that doesn't work, is to modify the to-be-drained record from latency based to weighted (with `weight=0`) but it seems Route53 doesn't allow mixing latency and weighted for the same record set.

Comment: what do you mean by `preemptively drain one instance`

Comment: Route53 is just a DNS service, there is no such thing as connection draining. You'd have to use ELB for such functionality

Comment: @ArunK See edit.

Comment: @karjan: DNS based traffic management, including draining, has been common practice in every multi region setup I've seen the details of. ELB based drains would work for things that are both within a region and behind the ELB, but not for the ELB it self.

Comment: Your solution does not look that sloppy, as technically, a "draining instance/endpoint" shouldn't be healthy.

Comment: @petern That kind of depends on your definition of "healthy": that it /can/ serve traffic, or that it /should/ serve traffic? In the specific situation to be handled, the answers are "yes" and "no": it can, but should not. -- Part of the sloppiness is that swapping the health check makes it hard to see if the service is health ("can") when you go to un-drain and also show up in monitoring history where it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to shift traffic in the event a host isn't there there are a number of steps you can take to try and make this as smooth as possible.

Firstly keep your TTLs low, otherwise any DNS configuration changes may take a while to be applied for clients who have cached the DNS resolution. This cached TTL is what I believe you are referring to by draining.

Secondly as you've mentioned keeping a health check will enable this to automatically remove that regions values from being returned during DNS lookups if the health check fails. Until the DNS cache clears for a client they will resolve to the broken region.

Alternatively depending on your scale it might be worth taking a look at [Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/). By using this service the configuration and failover between is handled at an application level meaning it will be much more instant for the end user. A single DNS record would then exist targeting the anycast IP that is provided by Global Accelerator.

**Edit**

It is possible to combine weighted with latency based records by making use of the value type of "alias" record. However. this would require multiple records as you cannot assigned both to the same record type.

More information is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialLBRMultipleEC2InRegion.html).

Comment: While that is useful information in general, each of those points are either things I've already done or not pertinent to the question I actually asked. -- The "downed host" case is actually already handled. What I'm looking to deal with is the upcoming "scheduled maintenance" type of case.

Comment: It is possible to use multiple record types (i.e. weighted and latency) by creating a chain of DNS records but thats not ideal and could over complicate it. My only suggestion would be taking a look at global accelerator as it provides additional functionality for distributing traffic across regions

Comment: How do those layers combine? I'd think latency stack on weighted would first chose a region and then, from that region pick by weight. But if each region only has one "instance", that would have no effect at the second layer. Anything going to the region would get either that one instance or `NXDOMAIN`. Stacking the other way would, I'd expect, fail similarly. If something more complex is going on; no thanks.

Comment: As for Global Accelerator, it's a non-starter for reason (extraneous to the question) that I can't go into.